# Displaying output of console.log to HTML in Node.js debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been having this issue for the past 6 or so hours and I can't figure it out. I followed examples perfectly, yet when I run my server, the console.log output does not get displayed on the html page. This is my first time messing with Node.js. Here is the code:

Server:

```
    require('dotenv').config()

var Twitter = require ('twitter');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var express = require ('express');

var events = require('events')

var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

// add API keys to .env file. .env_sample for details

var T = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

eventEmitter.on('logging', function(message) {
  io.emit('log_message', message);
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});

// Override console.log
var originConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function(data) {
  eventEmitter.emit('logging', data);
  originConsoleLog(data);
};

// code for test.
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('X: ' + Math.random());
}, 2000);


 /*T.get('statuses/home_timeline', function(error, tweets, response) {
  if(error) throw error;
  tweets.render
  console.log(tweets); // General Tweet Timeline

});*/
```

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang = "eng">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Twitter Client</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="/css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="/images/Twitter_Logo_Blue.png" height = "250" width = "250" alt="blue_bird">
    <h1> Using this simple twitter client, the user can view general tweets, specify a specific twitter handle, and search tweets by text. </h1>
    <ul id = "messages"></ul>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var socket = io();
            socket.on('log_message', function(msg){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what's going on, and this project is due shortly. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: you mean console.log in node ?

Comment: correct, I've been trying to output the console.log in node to an HTML page, I've looked around and its possible using sockets and the override method, but for some reason it's not working on my end.

Comment: you can emit event on socket.io. Straight forward way.

Comment: I'm still having troubles getting this to work... Are most of my errors in the HTML or the JS?

Comment: console.log in node js is unrelated to the front-end  (html you sended). So the easy way is the emit event from socket.io with the data you want  and the front-end intercept the event and log out the data.